# React-native-deck-swiper Not displaying first card with images fetched from firebase

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fast-image, react-native-deck-swiper

React-native-deck-swiper is not displaying first card with images fetched from firebase. Basically I fetch the image urls from firebase. Then I put them into the array currentPageIconArray as sources for the FastImage plugin elements inside touchableOpacity  . Then I set the array as data for FlatGrid. If I just put local image sources on FastImage like that source={require('./1.png')} into the currentPageIconArray it works fine but as soon I fetch the urls a from firebase and put the source as an uri uri: urlArray[i] then it's not displaying anymore. If I swipe to the next card it's starting to display images as soon I see the NEXT label (so it re-renders when the NEXT Overlay is getting visible?). I think it's a **re-render issue** or something because I see the images appearing as soon as the NEXT label is showing up during the swipe but the card is still not completely swiped away.

As cardindex I use a simple global variable not a state because otherwise it messes up the index. Then I would get indexes twice like 0,0,1,1,2,2,... and see the cards twice after swiping. So I fixed that.

displayImages I call in the useEffect hook once.

````
 const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    cards: [...range(0, 29)],
    swipedAllCards: false,
    swipeDirection: ''
  });


  const getFirebaseIcons = async (page) => {
    return storage.ref().child('pages/' + page).listAll()
      .then(res => {
        if (res.items.length > 0) {
          let sortedUrls = sortUrls(res.items);

          return getIconURLS('pages/' + page, sortedUrls)
            .then(urlArray => {
              return urlArray;
            })
            .catch(err => {
              alert(err.message);
            })
        } else {
          currentPageIconArray.length = 0;
          return null;
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err.message);
      })
  }


  const displayImages = async() => {
    let urlArray = await getFirebaseIcons(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
      {
        if (urlArray[i] != null) {
          currentPageIconArray.push(
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {

              }
              }>
              <FastImage
                style={{ width: squareSize, height: squareSize }}
                source={{
                  uri: urlArray[i],
                  headers: { Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
                  priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
                }}
                resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        } else {

          currentPageIconArray.push(
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {               
              }}>
              <FastImage
                style={{ width: squareSize, height: squareSize }}
                source={require('./1.png')}
                resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        }
      }
    }

    <View style={styles.container} key={cardIndex}>
      
        <Swiper
          ref={swpr => swiper = swpr}
          infinite={true}
          showSecondCard={false}
          keyExtractor={(cardidx) => { 
            //console.log("CARDINDEX = ", cardIndex); 
            //cardIndex = cardidx 
          }}
          goBackToPreviousCardOnSwipeLeft={true}
          onSwiped={(idx) => onSwiped('general', idx)}
          onSwipedLeft={(idx) => onSwipedLeft(idx)}
          onSwipedRight={(idx) => onSwipedRight(idx)}
          onSwipedTop={() => onSwiped('top')}
          onSwipedBottom={() => onSwiped('bottom')}
          onTapCard={swipeLeft}
          cards={state.cards}
          cardIndex={cardIndex}
          cardVerticalMargin={10}
          renderCard={renderCard}
          onSwipedAll={onSwipedAllCards}
          stackSize={1}
          stackSeparation={15}
          overlayLabels={{
            bottom: {
              title: '',
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: '',
                  borderColor: '',
                  color: 'white',
                  borderWidth: 1
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center'
                }
              }
            },
            left: {
              title: 'PREVIOUS',
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: 'red',
                  borderColor: 'black',
                  color: 'white',
                  borderWidth: 1
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  alignItems: 'flex-end',
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  marginTop: 30,
                  marginLeft: -30
                }
              }
            },
            right: {
              title: 'NEXT',
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: 'red',
                  borderColor: 'black',
                  color: 'white',
                  borderWidth: 1
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  alignItems: 'flex-start',
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  marginTop: 30,
                  marginLeft: 30
                }
              }
            },
            top: {
              title: '',
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: '',
                  borderColor: '',
                  color: 'white',
                  borderWidth: 1
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center'
                }
              }
            }
          }}
          animateOverlayLabelsOpacity
          animateCardOpacity
          swipeBackCard={false}
        >
        </Swiper>     
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>

  const renderCard = (card, index) => {

    return ( 
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <FlatGrid
          itemDimension={squareSize}
          maxItemsPerRow={10}
          adjustGridToStyles={true}
          data={**currentPageIconArray**}
          style={styles.gridView}
    
          spacing={4}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              {item}
            </View>
          )}
        />

      </View>
    )
  };

  const onSwiped = (type, index) => {
    cardIndex = index;
    getFirebaseIcons(cardIndex);
  }

```
````